# Generate random number in a float range

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

How we can generate randomize number between a range in the Float numbers (in delphi xe3) ?

For example, randomize number between `[0.10 to 0.90]`.
I need give results like:

`[ 0.20 , 0.32 , 0.10 , 0.50 ]`

Thanks for solutions....

Comment: 0.05 is not in range [0.10..0.90] why do you expect it in result ;o)

Comment: It was just a typographical mistake. ;)

Comment: the code in the accepted answer will not hit the upper range limit (0.9), is this ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var
  float : Double;

  float := Random;  // Random float in range: 0 <= float < 1
  float := 0.1 + float*0.8 // 0.1 <= float < 0.9
```

To initialize the Random number generator, make a single call to `Randomize`or set the `RandSeed` parameter before calling the [`Random`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Random) function for the first time.

Not doing so, generates the same sequence every time you run the program. Note however, that this sequence is not guaranteed when recompiling for another compiler version.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use [`RandomRange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Math.RandomRange) (returns: `AFrom <= r < ATo`) as follow:

```
RandomRange(10, 90 + 1) / 100
```

or

```
RandomRange(10, 90 + 1) * 0.01
```

will return numbers in the range of 0.10 to 0.90 (including 0.90)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function RandomRangeF(min, max: single): single;
begin
  result := min + Random * (max - min);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit cheeky but here goes: Depends how many numbers you want after the floating point. For example, if you want 1 number, you could generate in the 100 - 999 range and then divide by 10. Or 1000 - 9999 and divide by 100.

Comment: I think you could add a code to exemplify your thoughts